# predict_proba() Logistic Regression when predicting a single value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I want to use Logistic Regression to predict a class (-1 or +1) given a data set which I split as follows (only a single entry is to be predicted in the test set):

```
x_train, x_test = loc_indep[:-1], loc_indep[-1:]
y_train, y_test = loc_target[:-1], loc_target[-1:]
```

Then I use the following to train the model:

```
regr = LogisticRegression()
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = regr.predict(x_test)

probabilities = regr.predict_proba(x_test)
print(probabilities) # prints probabilities
```

Given the above, the  `probabilities`  always prints either [1. 0.] or [0. 1.], meaning that either class +1 or class -1 are picked with the probability 100%. Why is this the case? I expected that the probabilities sum to 1, but that the model picks, say, class +1 with probability 54%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct. So this means you have a supper accurate model (which makes me suspect that something is wrong...). I will recommend check your training data, maybe you have some variable, by error, that explains too much (for example the same output).

Also try to output the train an test accuracy. If train accuracy is 100% and test accuracy is much lower, you are over fitting. Then you will have to change some hyperparameters to avoid it.

To conclude, try to understand your data, maybe it's super easy to differentiate both classes, and maybe for this reason you obtain such a good model.